# Can I make one maven profile activate another?

Tags: java, maven-2

I have 2 maven2 profiles, selenium and jspc. Now for "selenium" id'd like to have an implicit activation of "jspc", so that I don't have to write mvn -Pselenium,jspc from the command line. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can't "chain" profile activations ([maven reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)) but you can activate them both through the same property:

```
<activation>
  <property>
    <name>profile.selenium</name>
  </property>
</activation>
```

And the run `mvn -Dprofile.selenium`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2248552/253686 has some more detail on *why* you can't chain.

Comment: Also, you can define activation based on properties NOT being there - this allows you to create mutually exclusive profiles (unless you force-activate both).  E.g.
<profile>
    <id>test-default</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>!profile.externalAndContractTests</name>
        </property>
    </activation>...

Comment: For my case, I have `profile1` extends `profile2` extends `profile3`, so the above would not work because activation only can use one property. Instead I just use `maven-enforcer-plugin` with `requireProperty` and paste the `mvn install -Dprofile1,profile2,profile3` inside the requireProperty->message. So everytime I just do `mvn install profile3`, get the warning and copy the output message and run again.

Comment: @bradley.ayers always someone trying to justify WHY. I can see 100 ways to implement this. Just look for profiles that match, unify them.