# Meta-profiles in Maven

Tags: maven-2, profile

I'm looking for a way to create meta-profiles that just activate sub-profiles in Maven. Let's take a very concrete example. I have the following profiles:

- "server-jboss"
- "server-tomcat"
- "database-hsql"
- "database-oracle"

To build the project, you have to choose one profile for the server and one for the database. I want to create two "meta-profiles":

- "dev" => "server-tomcat","database-hsql"
- "prod" => "server-jboss","database-oracle"

The first idea that comes is to activate the subprofiles by a property:

```
<profile>
   <id>database-oracle</id>
   <activation>
     <property>
       <name>prod</name>
     </property>
   </activation>
</profile>
```

But this way, I cannot share subprofiles between meta-profiles. For example, I want my profile "database-oracle" to be activated by both "pre-prod" and "prod" meta-profiles.

**Note: my sub-profiles just contain properties. They are used for filtering resources and in the child poms. This is why I think there could be a solution for this particular situation.**

The ideal situation for me would be to have them externalized in external properties files, but one issue at a time ;)

Comment: Actually, this question really sounds like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246033/why-cant-i-activate-a-maven2-profile-from-another-profile. Please confirm if you think it's a different question.

Comment: Yes, I browsed those questions, but I think there could be some trick in my situation. My sub-profiles are just sets of properties that I want to aggregate. May be the title of my question is a little bit ambitious ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Activating profiles from another profile is not possible (this has been discussed in this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246033/why-cant-i-activate-a-maven2-profile-from-another-profile)). Your first idea, using identical properties to activate different profiles, is the best thing you can implement but has indeed limitations.

Comment: In this case, is there a trick to make a profile activated by several properties ? I see you can use ranges for the jdk version for example, may be there is some hidden syntax like <property><name>pord,pre-prod</name></property> ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a solution using the maven-properties-plugin? Some possibilities are discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012402/maven2-property-that-indicates-the-parent-directory) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231561/how-to-share-common-properties-among-several-maven-projects/).

Comment: Yes, I tried it, it looked like a good solution. Unfortunately, I could not make it work correctly: I loaded properties files in the POM, it worked well for resources filtering, but not for using them directly in the POM.