# How to build a Maven module if a profile is activated and a property is not set?

Tags: maven, maven-profiles, maven-module

I've got 3 modules:

- Module1
- Module2
- Module3

and 3 profiles:

- Profile1
- Profile2
- Profile3

I'd like to build `Module1` if:

- `Profile2` or `Profile3` is activated, **and**
- Command-line property `skipModule1` is **not** set.

Regardless of whether `Module1` is built, `Profile2` and `Profile3` should build (both) modules `Module2` and `Module3`. **Can this be implemented in Maven 3? If so, how?**

The problem, as I see it, is that [profiles can't activate other profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2248552/14731)
and I can't include `Module1` as part of `Profile2` or `Profile3` because there is no way for me to specify that `Module1` should be skipped if `skipModule1` is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although profiles cannot activate other profiles, there is still a workaround you may take.

When building, instead of activating Profile2 and Profile3 explicitly (by `-P Profile2,Profile3`), activate them by using a variable, so that it looks like `mvn compile -DactivateProfile2=true -DactivateProfile3=true`.

Then your requirement on Profile1 become straight forward: Profile1 (which includes Module1) is activated by `activateProfile2=true, activateProfile3=true, !skipModule1`