# Maven: How to activate child profile using parent's activation criteria

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have a parent/root POM that (1) aggregates child modules, and (2) declares a profile that is conditionally activated based on a property value. So:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>moduleA</module>
    <module>moduleB</module>
    <module>moduleC</module>
</modules>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>myProfile</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>animal</name>
                <value>cat</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And in `moduleA`, I declare the same profile as the parent, and would like it to be activated when I build `moduleA` using the activation criteria from the parent (`animal == cat`). But that isn't working. So if this is moduleA's POM:

```
<properties>
    <shape>circle</shape>
</properties>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>myProfile</id>
        <properties>
            <shape>square</shape>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And I build `moduleA` using `mvn help:evaluate -Danimal=cat`, evaluating `${shape}` says its value is `circle`, not `square` as I'd expect. So it seems like the child profile is not activating when building using its parent's activation criteria.

Is there a way to do this? Do I really have to copy and paste the `<activation>` block from the parent into all its children modules, just so I can get the same behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Try repeating the activation criteria in moduleA. You shouldn't have to repeat other profile content from the parent, but the activation criteria need to match.

```
<profile>
    <id>myProfile</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>animal</name>
            <value>cat</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

Generally trying to share profile config from one module to another is tricky. There are other questions:

- [Activating a Child Profile from a Parent Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2246033/944849)
- [Why can't I activate a Maven2 profile from another profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2246033/944849)