# Activate multiple profiles from a profile

Tags: maven, maven-3, profiles

I have multiple profiles in maven like this,

`

```
    <profile>
         <id>one</id>
         <properties>
           <env>one</env>
         </properties>
   </profile>
   <profile>
        <id>two</id>
        <properties>
        <env>two</env>
        </properties>
   </profile>
   <profile>
        <id>three</id>
        <properties>
          <env>three</env>
        </properties>
   </profile>
   <profile>
    <id>four</id>
    <properties>
        <env>four</env>   
    </properties>
   </profile>`
```

My Question is how can i create a profile which can execute all of the profiles (**Except 
executing in command line -Pone,two,three,four**)??

Comment: I think this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943411/can-i-make-one-maven-profile-activate-another

Comment: I can confirm @wemu's comment will guide to the answer ;) (I however wont go that faar that this is a duplicate ;)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but above mentioned link says activating profiles through the same property. In my case i have different properties and its not chaining the profiles.

Comment: profiles support multiple activations. Can't you add a property "activateAll" and seperate ones for the other combinations?