# Activating a Child Profile from a Parent Profile

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-profiles

I have the following parent `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>build_full</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <modules>
        <module>mymodule_interface</module>
        <module>mymodule_switch</module>
        <module>mymodule_switch_simulator</module>
        <module>mymodule_switch_controller</module>
        <module>mymodule_server</module>
    </modules>
</profile>
```

and in my child pom for `mymodule_server`, I have the following:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>subprofile</id>
    <modules>
        <module>...various modules...</module>
    </modules>
</profile>  
<profile>
    <id>default</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <modules>
        <module>...various modules...</module>
    </modules>
</profile>
```

How, when I invoke maven:  `mvn -P build_full`, can I force the child module (`mymodule_server`) to use profile `subprofile` rather than `default`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't activate a child profile from a parent profile. More generally, [you can't activate or deactivate any profile from any other profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/943474/1743880) (there is a JIRA feature-request [MNG-3309](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3309)). What you can do is [activate two profiles based on the same property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2248552/1743880).

First of all, using a profile that is activated by default is generally not a good idea. What you want is to activate a profile based on some condition (OS version, system property...). To solve your problem, you can activate `build_full` profile when a certain system property is present, and make sure that `subprofile` is also activated when that same property is present.

A sample configuration would be the following, where both profiles are activated when the `fullBuild` system property is set to `true`. Invoking Maven with `mvn -DfullBuild=true ...` will thus activate both profiles.

```xml
<profile>
    <id>build_full</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>fullBuild</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <modules>
        <module>mymodule_interface</module>
        <module>mymodule_switch</module>
        <module>mymodule_switch_simulator</module>
        <module>mymodule_switch_controller</module>
        <module>mymodule_server</module>
    </modules>
</profile>
```

```xml
<profile>
    <id>subprofile</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>fullBuild</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <modules>
        <module>...various modules...</module>
    </modules>
</profile>
```

Comment: I just tested locally before posting my answer, I probably made a mistake, gonna re-test it then

Comment: @A.DiMatteo This should work when running from the parent POM. Your solution should work also but I'm not quite found of all the `-P` parameters (I think this is too fragile)

Comment: I confirm both solutions work well. Indeed your proposal is less verbose from command line and centralizes the activation in one common place, better.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, from the top parent/aggregator folder, you could just run:

```
mvn clean install -Pbuild_full,!default,subprofile
```

It will disable any profile having name `default` (and hence disable the profile in the concerned sub-module) and enable any profile having name `subprofile` (and hence enable the profile you wanted).

Alternatively, you could configure `subprofile` as such:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>subprofile</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>subprofile</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        ....
```

and then run as following:

```
mvn clean install -Dsubprofile=true -Pbuild_full
```

It will have the same effect. You can even avoid the `value` element and simply specify `-Dsubprofile`, its existence would be enough to activate the profile (in that case a more meaningful name is suggested, like `-DactivateSubprofile`). Since you active a different profile, automatically Maven will deactivate the default one.